Next.js Socket.io app router, is there any way to integrate socket io without creating custom server
I'm new to Nextjs, I'm trying to integrate socket.io into my application. I'm using the app router approach. I want to create an API folder with socket.ts file to register my socket.io server, without creating a custom server (as it doesn't make sense to me).
Is anyone can share the working configuration or any ideas, Thank you
I was trying to put api/socket.ts | socket/route | pages/socket/route on different levels, I tried to use the rewrite property in config which didn't help me either.
I tried next folder structures with different configurations, but I always have socket.io 404
+ api
++ socket.ts
+ app
++ home.tsx

+ pages
++ socket
+++ route.ts
+ app
++ home.tsx

+ app
++ home.tsx
++ api
+++ socket.ts

+ app
++ home.tsx
++ socket
+++ route.ts

